# How does iOS Safari determine when to show the location services dialog?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, geolocation

**How does iOS Safari determine when to show the location services dialog?** It seems if the user grants permission twice for a given domain, the choice is cached (just on that device). For how long? Are two denials also cached?

- Has the algorithm changed between versions of iOS? (On a version of iOS before 10.1.1, I always gave google.com permission, but I kept getting prompted every time I visited.)
- Is the algorithm different when the mobile app supports "save to home screen?" (And is started from the home screen)

*Background info:*

When a web app requests the user's location, iOS first prompts the user for permission. An example of this is on [google.com](https://google.com) when "Use precise location" at the bottom is tapped.

This question is similar, but there are no answers, yet: [How does mobile safari determine when to prompt user to share location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938080/how-does-mobile-safari-determine-when-to-prompt-user-to-share-location)

Comment: It is done using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback)`